# Is it possible to declare the conversion function returning array reference without the typedef?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, typedef, language-lawyer, conversion-operator

Here's a conversion function returning an array reference:

```
struct S { 
    typedef int int_array_20[20];
    operator int_array_20& ();
};
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without `typedef`? What I've tried:

```
struct S { 
    operator int (&()) [10];
};
```

but clang complains:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    operator int (&()) [10];
                  ~ ^
error: conversion function cannot have any parameters
    operator int (&()) [10];
    ^
error: must use a typedef to declare a conversion to 'int [10]'
error: conversion function cannot convert to an array type
```

Does:

> must use a typedef to declare a conversion to 'int [10]'

mean `typedef` is indispensable?

**EDIT**
If `typedef` is necessary, it's impossible to create a conversion function template like the following, because couldn't define a `typedef` template, is it right?

```
struct S { 
    template<typename T, int N>
    operator T(&())[N];
};
```

Comment: Yes, you must use `typedef` as it clearly tells you.

Comment: I really don't want to follow this chain right now, but start here: http://i.imgur.com/1eqfyiW.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed required we can see this by going to the cppreference section [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) which says:

> Function and array operators [] or () are not allowed in the
>   declarator (thus conversion to types such as pointer to array requires
>   a typedef: see below). Regardless of typedef, conversion-type-id
>   cannot represent an array or a function type.

We can find this in the draft C++ standard section `12.3.2` *Conversion functions* which says:

> The conversion-type-id shall not represent a function type nor an
>   array type. The conversion-type-id in a conversion-function-id is the
>   longest possible sequence of conversion-declarators. [ Note: This
>   prevents ambiguities between the declarator operator * and its
>   expression counterparts. [ Example:
>
> ```
> &ac.operator int*i; // syntax error:
>                     // parsed as: &(ac.operator int *)i
>                     // not as: &(ac.operator int)*i
> ```
>
> The * is the pointer declarator and not the multiplication operator. —end example ] —end note ]

and the grammar for *conversion-type-id* is as follows:

> ```
> conversion-type-id:
>   type-specifier-seq conversion-declaratoropt
> conversion-declarator:
>   ptr-operator conversion-declaratoropt
> ```

which is more restricted then a *declarator* whose grammar looks like this:

> ```
> declarator:
>   ptr-declarator
>   noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type
> ptr-declarator:
>   noptr-declarator
>   ptr-operator ptr-declarator
> noptr-declarator:
>   declarator-id attribute-specifier-seqopt
>   noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   noptr-declarator [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
>   ( ptr-declarator )
> ```

One alternative as chris mentioned was to use an identity class:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

you would use it as follows:

```
operator typename identity<int(&)[10]>::type() ;
```

Comment: I took the standard to not cover a reference to an array by that.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Could you see my edit of post? Is it impossible to create a conversion function template like that?

Comment: @songyuanyao, I imagine with some sort of `id` template etc., you can do `operator typename id<T(&)[N]>::type()` (or a bit better in C++11).

Comment: @chris Even better with a `using` alias.

Comment: @0x499602D2, Yes, that would be the C++11 bit. I'm not sure why, but I had the notion that the question had something that suggested it wasn't C++11, but that would just be me getting random notions.